# Rational function and pole

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, rational-functions

Suppose $R(z)$ be a rational function such that $|R(z)|=1$ for $|z|=1$. Show that $\alpha$ is a zero or a pole or order $m$, if and only if $1/\overline{\alpha}$ is a pole or zero or order $m$ respectively.

I am wondering that if I can first show that $M(z)=R(z)$ the complex conjugate of $R(1/z)$ is a rational function such that $M(z)=1$ on $|z|=1$. Can I assume $z=1$ and then substitute all $z$ with $1$? Thank you very much.

Comment: I haven't learnt such things...

Comment: Apply the [Schwarz reflection principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_reflection_principle) (reflection around $|z| = 1$) but starting from $g(z) = i \log R(z)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. Note that $F(z):= R(z)\cdot \overline{R(1/\overline{z})}$ is a the rational function such that for $|z|=1$:
$$F(z)=R(z)\cdot \overline{R(1/\overline{z})}=R(z)\cdot \overline{R(z)}=|R(z)|^2=1.$$
Since a non-constant rational function attains a value only finitely often, it follows that $F$ is identically equal to $1$. Hence
$$R(1/\overline{z}) = \frac{1}{\overline{R(z)}}.$$

Comment: what is your argument for showing it is entire ?

Comment: @user1952009 Is it more convincing now?

Comment: instead of "a rational function attains a value only finitely often" I'd say that "a non-constant holomorphic function takes a given value only finitely often on some compact"